# I can't install laravel/socialite package using composer

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-socialite

laravel-version: 7.24.0

os: windows

I run the following command in the command prompt.
`composer require laravel/socialite`
but it fails and the output is :

```
D:\...\xxx>composer require laravel/socialite
Using version ^4.4 for laravel/socialite
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 2 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing league/oauth1-client (1.7.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing laravel/socialite (v4.4.1): Loading from cache
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

  Class 'Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider' not found


Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I've tried dump-autoload, and clear configs but anything didn't help me.

Comment: Goto bootstrap/cache/packages.php file and try  finding the laravel socialite class and then remove it and then try again with composer

Comment: i had removed ```laravel/socialite``` and ```packages.php``` has no socailite class.
but still not working.

Comment: CHeck in config/app.php file also for this line SocialiteServiceProvider

Comment: checked also ```config/app.php```, but can't find ```SocialiteServiceProvider```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because `socialite` package wasn't really installed.
I've checked `vender/laravel` directory, and `socialite` wasn't installed.
`composer` tried to download `socialite` package but failed. But `composer` ignores the fail of `socialite` package, so after `composer` command completed, they can't find  `Class 'Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider'`.
I'm not sure why downloading `socialite` package, but I think it's mostly network problem(slow speed or blocked ip location, etc).
So I solved by copying `socialite` package to `vendor` directory.